# Jquery Mobile reset form html 5

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a form which I want to reset when I push a button. But I just can't seem to get it working. It seems like the input type range is reset, but not the select's.

**HTML**

```
   <form id="details_to_add">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <select id="select_company" data-native-menu="false" onchange="openNewcompanyDialog(this)" value="Company">
                        <option data-placeholder="company">Company</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="test">Test</option>
                        <option value="internal1">Internal</option>
                        <option value="new_company_option">Add a new company</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <select id="select_description" data-native-menu="false" onchange="handleInternalChoice(this)" value="Description">
                        <option data-placeholder="description">Description</option>

                        <!--Options to be shown when "internal" is chosen from company -->
                        <option value="internal1_1">Day off</option>
                        <option value="internal1_2">Time off</option>
                        <option value="internal1_3">Vacation</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="number_of_hours">Number of hours:</label>
                    <input type="range" id="number_of_hours" value="0" min="0" max="24" step="0.25" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Close</a>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" onclick="pushData()">Save</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I have tried a bunch of ways to reset this form, but as mentioned above it only resets the slider.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it adding a button like this:

```
<a id="reset" data-role="button">Reset</a>
```

And with a little help of jQuery...

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#number_of_hours').val('0').slider('refresh');
    $('#select_company').val('Company').selectmenu('refresh');
    $('#select_description').val('Description').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

Try the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KxakF/6/